# How to save and reload current frame using SharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem using SharedObject to save and reload data. I want to save currentFrame of movieClip and reload. I am successful in storing current frame. but have problem to reload it. How it reload when loading. I hope who khow, will help me.
thanks in advance

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Test");
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
so.data.saveData = doll_mc.currentFrame;
so.flush();
}
function reloadBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
doll_mc.currentFrame = so.data.saveData
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currentFrame is read only. You want to use "gotoAndStop()"

```
   var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Test");
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
so.data.saveData = doll_mc.currentFrame;
so.flush();
}
function reloadBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    doll_mc.gotoAndStop(so.data.saveData);
)
```

Comment: Yes it is well. But which way in, a person can save the the complete data (including data in text boxes and movie clips' status etc) of current frame using shared object? I have not tried this yet.

Comment: @user3398010 You'll want to save the Data as an object, rather than a single value.  like so.data.saveData = {frame:doll_mc.currentFrame, status: "dressed", text: "some text" }
And then do doll_mc.gotoAndStop(so.data.saveData.frame);